# How to clear temp folder in php even after deleting files from a folder in C-Panel?

Tags: php

I have created a portal in PHP where there is a cron job. Now what the cron job is doing is that, it is creating a PDF from static HTML page using DomPDF library and then uploading the pdf file to AWS S3 bucket. So, what I have done is that, I have created a folder in my server where the PDF files are getting stored and then uploading the same file to AWS S3 bucket and then finally removing the PDF file from the folder. The entire logic is working fine. So, how can I empty the tmp folder also in c-panel?

But the problem is that, even after removing the file from the folder, the tmp folder in C-panel is getting loaded with the pdf files. So I can't understand why the tmp folder is getting filled with PDF files which I am deleting in my PHP code.

```
<?php
function callDompdf($outputtempl,$i,$templateno,$cust_details,$db){
    ob_start();
    include $outputtempl;
    //echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/funnel_webhooks/pdfgenerate/'.$outputtempl;
    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    //$contents=file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/funnel_webhooks/pdfgenerate/'.$outputtempl);
    //if($contents!==false){
        $fullname=str_replace(' ','_',$cust_details['full_name']);
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->loadHtml($contents);
        $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
        $options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true, 'isJavascriptEnabled'=>true));
        $dompdf->setOptions($options);
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        $pdf = $dompdf->output();
        $filename='reading_'.$i.'_'.$templateno.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.$fullname.'_'.time().'.pdf';
        $filepath='pdf/'.$filename;
        $data=file_put_contents($filepath,$pdf);
        uploadToaws($filename,$cust_details,$db);
        unset($dompdf);
        unset($data);
        //$dompdf->stream();
}
function uploadToaws($file_name,$cust_details,$db){
    require 'aws3/autoload.php';
   
    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
    'key'    => "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    'secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ]
    ]);
   
    //create folder monthwise
    $monthNum  = date('m');
    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
    $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
    $year=date('Y');
    $foldername='report_'.'_'.$monthName.'_'.$year;

    if (!file_exists($foldername)) {
        $newfoldername=$foldername;
    }else{
        $newfoldername=$foldername;
    }
   
    $source = 'pdf/'.$file_name;
    $uploader = new Aws\S3\MultipartUploader($s3, $source, [
        'bucket' => 'bbbbbbbbbbb',
        'key' => $newfoldername.'/'.$file_name,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
   
    try {
        $result = $uploader->upload();
        $objUrl=$result['ObjectURL'];
        $replaceURL=str_replace("s3.amazonaws.com/", "", $objUrl);
        $update_Getresponse=$db->updateGetresponse($cust_details['id'],$replaceURL);
        $path = 'pdf/'.$file_name;
    if (file_exists($path)){
       unlink($path);
    }
     
    } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}options=
}
```